# How To Do Task Repeatedly In Java 1.6

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Timer Won't Fire Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287106/timer-wont-fire-correctly)

Apparently, in Java 1.6, the `Timer` doesn't work like it used to, so how do I get a task to fire every 250ms (1/4 of a second)?

Comment: [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) or [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)?

Comment: What do you mean by *it doesn't work like it used to*? The API looks pretty much the same to me. You can still schedule tasks for fixed interval execution with Java6. Is there some specific behaviour that you need that's not in Java6 API?

Comment: -1: wtf?  I hate leaving flyby downvotes but I really don't know what to say here.  You really think they just disabled timers in 1.6?  Any information source?  Have you looked through the APIs?  Where is your code sample--what do you currently have?  Give us SOMETHING to work with here.

Comment: My problem was that i was using the Swing timer instead of the java.util.Timer.

Comment: Yeah, it's firing as fast as it can instead of every 250ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do task every 250ms even doStuff() may take more than 250ms, you should use a new thread to "doStuff"(In this case, more than one doStuff may work at a time)

updated(I tried this in win7x64, JDK 1.6 and it works)

```
    java.util.TimerTask task = new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("yoo");
        }
    };
    java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), 250);
```

Comment: One problem, it's not firing every 250ms, it's firing as fast as it can. How do I use it in another thread.

Comment: I tried and it worked every 250ms. The last "250" for schedule is the time