# Exiting an infinite loop with a button - Java

Tags: java, swing

I've searched for a solution for my problem all over but I cannot find anything close. Here is my problem: I have just started to learn Swing in Java and I have an application that will click randomly between a min and max amount of time. The user enters a min and max time and clicks a button which starts this code:

```
    class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //get data from text fields and store as integers in milliseconds. 

        //create a robot and random number between min and max

        while(run == true){

            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.delay(num.nextInt(max-min+1)+min);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've removed some code because it wasn't relevant to the issue.
The problem is I have another button to set the variable run to false but once the first button is clicked, I can't click the second button or the exit button at the top for that matter.

I'm sure my mistake is a very basic one but I can't see it.
Thank you for any replies that help me better understand the subject.

Edit: Changed the while loop from "while (run = true)" to "while (run == true)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 while(run == true){
```

"=" sets run to true
"==" compares the value of run to true

Also you can just use

```
 while(run){
```

Comment: You are very correct and in my program I caught it after I posted this and ended up changing it to a for loop for testing reasons. The problem is I can't break the loop later on; I believe it is answered below. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SwingWorker](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SwingworkerExample.htm). And just do `while(run)`

Comment: Since the comment indicates that a `Robot` will be making clicks, maybe it's not a good idea to do this off the EDT.

Answer (score 2):

Every event will be processed by a single thread called Event Dispatch thread(EDT). If you have an infinite call inside one of the events, EDT cannot process the next event in the event queue.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
This answer is updated, because @uckelman pointed me out that, with the condition `run = true`, the stop button never breaks the while loop, because it's needed to change to run = false within the loop. Then I post a simple and alternative solution to this logic problem, to schedule a task repeatedly with a timer. For details, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283734/how-to-do-task-repeatedly-in-java-1-6) SO question.

About the events for the buttons: if you have two buttons, one to start a loop and one to end the loop, just try this code:

```
    class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        private boolean run = true;
        private java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
        private JButton start_loop, end_loop;

        //here the buttons initialization


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if(ae.getSource()==start_loop){


            java.util.TimerTask task = new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doStuff();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), 500);//here the '500' means the time, 500 ms,
the task is repeatedly executed. 


        }

        if(ae.getSource()==end_loop){
            timer.cancel();//cancel the tasks scheduled
            System.out.println("Task cancelled!");
        }
    }

    private void doStuff(){
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            robot.delay(num.nextInt(max-min+1)+min);


    }
    }
```

Now, the task `doStuff()` is scheduled to be executed each 500 ms.

Other info about [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [java.util.TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html).

About your problem:

> The problem is I have another button to set the variable run to false
>   but once the first button is clicked, I can't click the second button
>   or the exit button at the top for that matter.

As in a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259127/changing-color-of-a-java-graphic-object/8259454#8259454), and in [this](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads3.html) page, it's written this:

> Swing's single-thread rule says that Swing components can only be
>   accessed by a single thread. This rule applies to both gets and sets,
>   and the single thread is known as the event-dispatch thread.
>
> The single-thread rule is a good match for UI components because they
>   tend to be used in a single-threaded way anyway, with most actions
>   being initiated by the user. Furthermore, building thread safe
>   components is difficult and tedious: it's a good thing not to be doing
>   if it can be avoided. But for all its benefits, the single-thread rule
>   has far-reaching implications.
>
> Swing components will generally not comply with the single-thread rule
>   unless all their events are sent and received on the event-dispatch
>   thread. For example, property-change events should be sent on the
>   event-dispatch thread, and model-change events should be received on
>   the event-dispatch thread.
>
> For model-based components such as JTable and JTree, the single-thread
>   rule implies that the model itself can only be accessed by the
>   event-dispatch thread. For this reason, the model's methods must
>   execute quickly and should never block, or the entire user interface
>   will be unresponsive.

Then, if you develop your GUI using a single Thread, when a button event is executed, your GUI will freeze, waiting for the complete execution of the related button event. In your case, on a infinite loop, your GUI will always freezing.

My suggestion is to use, for your GUI, a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), or extend the [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class (then developing the GUI in a separate thread), or implement the [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface. Another alternative is the using of a [Timer](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=java%20timer%20api%206&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html&ei=EtjlTv7QDNTU4QSc6PT4BA&usg=AFQjCNGLmIeZSfJ-C8j_mUDrZPdfIEpywQ&sig2=Q_rjjHXyopQD2dXLm5FBCw) from the `javax.swing.Timer` package.

You can read this old question of SO about SwingWorker: [How do I use SwingWorker in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java)

A tutorial for SwingWorker : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

A tutorial to make a Thread : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

A question about `Timer`: [Update JPanel and attributes in a gui, with a user-specified timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237085/update-jpanel-and-attributes-in-a-gui-with-a-user-specified-timer/8237370#8237370)

A tutorial about Timer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: @mKorbel Thank you. I know the suggestion with the getSource() in a separate actionPerformed method, it isn't the best (it's better to do it through inner classes), but it's the first thing that came to my mind. :-)

Comment: This can't work, because `run` is never set to `false` within the `while (run)` loop.

Comment: @uckelman Why this cannot work? ---> if(ae.getSource()==end_loop) run = false;

Comment: @AlbertoSolano: That assignment is after the while loop. Once control enters the while loop, your program will keep looping so long as `run` is true. But `run` is never assigned to inside the while loop.

Comment: @uckelman You're right. Like you said,it's a logic problem. I will update the answer using a Timer to do the task repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about Swing timers:

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/timer/

That is, make your program event-driven. Swing applications already have a loop running inside them all the time, called the event loop. It doesn't help if you start another one.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about method like `while(something)`, this could make the program frezee, i recommend you to implement ***events listeners*** to avoid this problems...

Answer (score 0):

```
run=true;
while(run == true){
```

...

Answer (score 0):

`while (run = true)` is almost certainly not what you want. What that does is assigns `true` to `run` each time the loop condition is executed, which ensures that the loop will always continue.

What you were probably trying to say was `while (run == true)` which only tests whether `run` is true. Better is just to say `while (run)`, which does the same thing.

If you're assigning to `run` from a different thread, note that you ought to make `run` a `volatile` member of your class. If you're *not* assigning to `run` somewhere else, then you have a logic bug, since there's no way to break out of the loop. In that case, you need to add a test inside the loop and set `run` to false when you want the loop to stop. (Or, you could have `while (true)` and just use a `break` inside the loop.)